# Changing catalog/product_list Block Template

Tags: layout, template, blocks

I'm changing the `<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">` template using another handler:

```
<other_custom_handler>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>custom/module/catalog/product/list.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <remove name="advancedmenu.sidenav" />
</other_custom_handler>
```

`other_custom_handler` is already a working handler, however, instead of copying `catalog/product/list.phtml` to custom module template, I want it to be more dynamic using the said method. It's not working.

**Update:**

Here are the layout handles:

```
array(7) {
  [0] => string(7) "default"
  [1] => string(8) "cms_page"
  [2] => string(17) "STORE_otherstore_default"
  [3] => string(28) "THEME_frontend_othertheme_default"
  [4] => string(15) "cms_index_index"
  [5] => string(21) "page_two_columns_left"
  [6] => string(19) "customer_logged_out"
}
```

I created a CMS page that displays all the products using catalog/product_list block. Products are displaying correctly, fyi.

Comment: what do you mean by "dynamic" ? could you please explain it little bit ?

Comment: I have multiple handlers that need to have different templates, ie., other_custom_handler uses template1.phtml, other_custom_handler_2 uses template2.phtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two possibilities for this *non-working-layout-update* if you are sure about your *custom handler* is a proper working handler.

1. `other_custom_handler` is not including in the *category view* page. You handler may be working, but you need to make sure this handler is triggering in *category view* page.
2. if `other_custom_handler` is triggering in *category view* page, then you should ensure that, this custom handler is used only after `catalog_category_default` or `catalog_category_layered` layout handlers are processed. This is because, the block `product_list` is available only after either of these layout handles are processed, so that you can ***refer it*** through your custom layout handles.

Most probably , the second case may be issue.. Take care of these points.

### EDIT - 1

So you are adding `product_list` via CMS Page (through admin). So this will ceases the possibilities for updating  the `product_list` block via any *layout-update file*, since Magento considers CMS Page custom layout updates after processing all of the above mentioned handlers.

If you want to modify, the `product_list` block, the only possibility is update it programmatically and it will be difficult to implement though.

Comment: Ok I got it now. Here's what I did, I created a CMS page that displays all the products (product listing). Since you said catalog_category_default should be triggered, I figured it out that it's not. See my update.

Comment: okay how did you put the product listing in cms page ?

Comment: Yes, I did put the product listing in the cms and the products are displaying correctly.

Comment: nope that is not what i asked.. how did you put it ? Means via content section or via custom layout update for cms page ?

Comment: I updated answer.